# Where can I find my Android backup?

Tags: google-backup

Where can I find my Android backup in my Google account?
What is the name of my android backup in my android device?

Comment: Do you mean the backup of your contacts etc? That is saved on Google's servers, not on the device. It is preformed through your Google account, I can't remember the name of the services that do it. (Contacts Backup is one afaik)

Comment: Is there a specific problem you are trying to solve? Do you need to extract something from a backup? More context will allow us to help you better.

Comment: What do you mean by Android backup?
Your contacts ? Your emails? Apps you've downloaded from Playstore? Or your photos/videos?

Answer (score 1):

Google does not backup your whole Android device.
Only your apps, and, if you have a nexus device (< not sure), the app's data will be backed up. And if you turned on automatic camera backup in the Google Photos app, your photos are backed up, too

You can't download these backup from your PC or another device.
To restore it you have to login on a new/factory reset device. Then it will ask you to restore your apps.